# reading subfolders with Spark Streaming 1.6

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I am reading a directory where partitioned JSON files are being written, eg **auto2.0/databases/ss_aut_ctc_dev_b.db/partition=20190311/files**, but when a message arrives in another partition Spark cannot see this file.

I use the following function to read:

`JavaDStream dStream = ssc.textFileStream(path);`

And the path I'm going through is being **"auto2.0/databases/ss_aut_ctc_dev_b.db/*"**

But spark doesn't read anything that arrives and saves in some partition folder.

I'm using Spark 1.6 with Java.

Can anyone tell me if spark can read these subfolders automatically

Comment: Try `auto2.0/databases/ss_aut_ctc_dev_b.db/**/*` instead

Comment: Spark reads all subfolders automatically. What do you mean "when a message arrives in another partition Spark cannot see this file."